# How to override Contact Us Page (form.phtml) in Magento

Tags: content-management-system, magento-1.7

Here is what I do know:

One: To link a static block to a .phtml page I add the following PHP in the proper location of the .phtml file:

```
<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')
    ->setBlockId('my_custom_block')->toHtml() ?>
```

And create my static block in the Admin section.

Done.

Two: If I upgrade Magento, the form.phtml file I edited will be overridden since it is a core file.

Three:  I need to create a duplicate form.phtml and place it in my somewhere in my theme. Let's call my theme **"customtheme"** for clarity.

Four:  I need to go to admin > configuration > design and add **customtheme** as the default theme.  Perhaps I have to add it in templates and/or layout as well.

My Question:

I have done all four things.  I have created a directory app/design/frontend/default/customtheme/template/contacts/form.phtml and cleared the cache and I find no changes.

To make sure that my changes should be noticed, I edited the core form.phtml located in app/design/frontend/base/default/template/contacts/form.phtml and my changes were seen.

**My Question: What directory should I be placing my custom form.phtml file in to ensure my changes do not get discarded on an upgrade and to ensure magento loads this file instead of the core form.phtml file?**

Comment: Ahh... I have found my answer.  My package name is ultimo and my default theme is kokorugs.  The correct path was app/design/frontend/ultimo/default/template/contacts/form.phtml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ahh... I have found my answer. My package name is ultimo and my default theme is kokorugs. The correct path was app/design/frontend/ultimo/default/template/contacts/form.phtml